# ¿Qué debo hacer con los .hpp que tienen sus definiciones/implementaciones escritas en un .cpp?

Tags: c++, poo

He visto varias librerías que no son header-only e incluyen las implementaciones de sus funciones en archivos .cpp y no en el mismo header, por ejemplo:

###### A.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef __A_HPP
#define __A_HPP

class A {
    private:
      int B;
    public:
      int get();
      void set(int C);
      ~A();
};

// Los define

#endif
```

###### A.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"

void A::set(int C) {
    B = C;
}

int A::get() {
    return C;
}

A::~A() {
    B = 0;
}

// Los implementa
```

Qué debo hacer con ellos o cómo incluyo esas implementaciones/cuerpo de la función en mi proyecto/el header? porque al incluir únicamente el .hpp hay un obvio error con el linker que te muestra que las funciones y variables no están implementadas.

Comment: En el cpp no está incluyendo definiciones sino implementaciones, es decir, el código de las funciones. Lo que tienes que hacer es compilar esos archivos y, seguidamente, usar los código objeto generados para generar el ejecutable final

Comment: Añade `a.cpp` con los otros `.cpp` con los que estas compilando. Seria bueno que nos indicaras que estas usando para compilar, así te podríamos dar instrucciones mas precisas de como hacerlo.

Comment: @eferion Cómo los incluyo? uso MSVC para windows y clang en linux

Comment: @Pablochaches los mencioné en mi último comentario, cómo es que agrego a.cpp con los otros .cpp?

Comment: y gracias por la corrección acerca de las definiciones e implementaciones.

Comment: Con visual studio tendrías las opción de agregar los archivos en `Nuevo>Archivo` (Aunque no estoy seguro de como agregar archivos existentes, ya hace mucho que no uso VS). Con clang únicamente tienes que agregarlo con los otros en la linea de comandos. Digamos en lugar de `clang main.cpp -o a.out` harías `clang main.cpp a.cpp -o a.out`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explicación

- Los ficheros .hpp deben contener las cabeceras (o definiciones) de las clases y funciones que quieras usar. Si forma parte de un método (o en general de una clase) pueden contener código.
  Esto es útil por ejemplo para optimización en donde deseas que se produzca "inlining".
- Los ficheros .cpp deben contener código que deseas que vaya a ser compilado y linkado.
- A la hora de hacer un include **siempre** lo haremos contra los `.hpp` y **nunca** contra un `.cpp`.
- En condiciones normales compilaremos los `.cpp` a objetos (ficheros `.o`) para reducir los tiempos de compilación que posteriormente linkaremos en el ejecutable final. También podemos hacerlo del tirón en un único paso.

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

## Ejemplo funcional:

#### A.hpp

```cpp
#ifndef __A_HPP
#define __A_HPP

class A
{
private:
    int B = 0;

public:
    int get();
    void set(int C);
    ~A();
};

// Los define

#endif
```

#### A.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"

void A::set(int C)
{
    B = C;
}

int A::get()
{
    return B;
}

A::~A()
{
}

// Los implementa
```

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include "A.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A a;

    a.set(42);

    cout << a.get() << endl;
}
```

### Compilación y ejecución:

#### Linux & g++

`g++ A.cpp main.cpp -o main && ./main`

Salida:

```
42
```

#### Linux & clang

`clang -lstdc++ A.cpp main.cpp -o main && ./main`

Salida:

```
42
```

#### Linux & clang con binarios parciales:

```sh
clang -c -o A.o A.cpp
clang -c -o main.o main.cpp
clang -o main main.o A.o -lstdc++
./main
```

Salida:

```
42
```